# How can I install OpenCL on Kali Linux?

Tags: kali-linux

I had the *tar* file that I have downloaded from official website.

I did unzipping the files and I installed the *rpm* files and *tar* files.
These are the files

```
intel-opencl-cpu-r5.0-63503.x86_64.rpm
intel-opencl-cpu-r5.0-63503.x86_64.tar.xz
intel-opencl-cpu-r5.0-63503.x86_64.tar.xz.sig
intel-opencl-devel-r5.0-63503.x86_64.rpm
intel-opencl-devel-r5.0-63503.x86_64.tar.xz
intel-opencl-devel-r5.0-63503.x86_64.tar.xz.sig
intel-opencl-r5.0-63503.x86_64.rpm
intel-opencl-r5.0-63503.x86_64.tar.xz
intel-opencl-r5.0-63503.x86_64.tar.xz.sig
vpg_ocl_linux_rpmdeb.public
```

But when I am running the command

```
root@HANUSH:~# hashcat --benchmark
hashcat (pull/1273/head) starting in benchmark mode...

* Device #2: Intel's OpenCL runtime (GPU only) is currently broken.
             We are waiting for updated OpenCL drivers from Intel.
             You can use --force to override, but do not report related errors.
* Device #4: Not a native Intel OpenCL runtime. Expect massive speed loss.
             You can use --force to override, but do not report related errors.
No devices found/left.

Started: Sat Oct 14 11:23:55 2017
Stopped: Sat Oct 14 11:23:56 2017
```

it is showing like this.

If possible please tell me how to update the *opencl*?

If possible please tell me how to install *tar.xz.sig*?

I didn't install those.

Comment: What do you mean exactly with: "I installed the rpm files and tar files"?

Comment: it wasn't a duplicate. it's just not fare.